# HL7 Segment - Message type Vs segments

Tags: hl7, mirth, hl7-v2

Are there any restrictions on the Segments that should be used for a Specific message type? For Ex: If I have to create a sample HL7 ADT^A05 or REF message.. Can I include any segment that I like, or HL7 has some rules defined to choose the segments for  specific message type?

Is the below Hl7 Message correct?

```
MSH|^~&|DASH|DASH-GCD|CentralLogic|COCXXX|20130730183557||REF^I12|20130730183339|P|2.3.1|||AL|AL
PID|0||26||Test^Patient^^^||19950115|M|||||Phone#^Email||||||SSN#|PD1|||||PCP FName^LName|RF1|Pending|Patient ETA|Direct Admit|Doc-to-Doc|Critical|Admission#||||Note Info|PRD|RP|Smith^Ken^|1600 Medical Center Way^^Eureka^CA^95521||(707)555-5555||NPI#PRD|RT|Pacific Heart Group^Physician Name|Admitting Facility Name||(707)444-8300
NUP|Bed Location|Bed StatusIN1|1|||Insurance Company Name|Patient Gr ID|Patient Member ID||||||||IN2|Insured’s Employee ID|Insured’s Social Security Number|Insured’s Employer Name|OBX|1|CE|1010.1^BODY WEIGHT||154|LBOBX|2|CE|1010.1^HEIGHT||75|INDG1|1|I9|786.59|Chest pain||DG1|2|I9|794.31|Sun Burn||AL1|1|DRUG|Codeine|AL1|2|DRUG|PCN|RXO|CE|Albuterol 2.5 mg via Ben q6h prn sob||||||ODT|CE||Test Instruction
```

Comment: Question doesn't seem related to hl7-fhir.  Can you remove the tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are restrictions defined by HL7 on the segment to use. That being said, your messages will also be defined by the data exchange needs of the systems you are interfacing, and for that you should develop a specification.

The specification (conformance profile) would contain:

- Message types (trigger events)
- Supported segment list for each trigger event
- Supported fields
- Suported codes for coded fields
- Details about data semantic

This article explains what goes into a spec:  http://caristix.com/blog/2013/02/hl7-survival-guide-chapter-6-hl7-interface-specifications/.  It gives several reference sources.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** HL7 defines sets of messages and recommended segments. Exact valid form depends on the **HL7 conformance profile** that your and the-other system support.

For an example of conformance profiles and some tool to use it see e.g. http://hl7api.sourceforge.net/conformance.html

**2.** For list of conceptually valid segments in particular messages check appropriate version of the **HL7 specification** at http://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=185.

In case of your message take a look at "HL7 Messaging Standard Version 2.3.1".
For more up-to-date specification with better description look at "HL7 Messaging Standard Version 2.5" as this version is said to be (no proof available) most elaborate out of the HL7 2.x range.

**3.** For conceptual overview of messages and their meaning and system-wide **IHE integration profiles** refer to recommendations provided by http://www.ihe.net/Technical_Frameworks/

**4.** Useful piece of **software** that can help you diagnose/**validate** basic HL7 structure is [Inner Harbour Software's HL7Spy](http://ihs.48thave.com/hl7-spy/)

I'm not an expert just providing some links to get you started

Comment: An implementer may also define Z-segment to include "_clinical or patient data that the HL7 Standard may not have defined in other areas. When using Z segments, it is important to have adequate documentation of what is included._".

Comment: @user3005941 yes, for instance [Messaging Workbench](http://gforge.hl7.org/gf/project/mwb/frs/) and [Gazelle](http://gazelle.ihe.net/content/hl7-conformance-profiles-and-hl7-tables-management) are tools for documenting and validation of the **HL7 conformance profiles** in a machine readable XML formats. Free form textual documentation aka **DICOM conformance statement** was used in the past. Exact valid form always depends on both communicating systems. **IHE** provides some guideliness as to what should be send where and when, e.g. http://www.ihe.net/technical_frameworks/#radiology

Answer (score 0):

This will be helpful
The segments list with their specification composites/fields.

http://www.mexi.be/documents/hl7/htindex.htm 
or this other one 
http://www.hosinc.com/products/interfaces/interface_documentation.htm