# HL7 ADT^A03 - End Visit Notification

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

I just wanted to know When we send a End Visit Notification as Hl7 Message ,Can we include the below segments in the Hl7 Message ( ADT^A03) when we send End Visit Notification ?

- AIL -   Appointment Information - Location Resource
- AL1-   Patient Allergy Information
- CON - Consent Segment
- CTD -  Contact Data
- DG1 -  Diagnosis
- DMI -   DRG Master File Information
- FAC   - Facility
- IAM  -  Patient Adverse Reaction Information
- LAN    -Language Detail
- NTE -- Notes and Comments
- ODS --  Dietary Orders, Supplements, and Preferences
- PD1 --  Patient Additional Demographic
- PID   - Patient Identification
- PR1 -- Procedures
- PRA --  Practitioner Detail
- PRB  -- Problem Details
- PRD Provider Data
- PV1 Patient Visit
- PV2 Patient Visit - Additional Information
- RF1 Referral Information
- TCD Test Code Detail

And also I just wanted to know, Is there a limit on using the no of segments in a single HL7 Message?

Any help with this really appreciated it?

Thanks
Ramana

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. See answers in question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23525727/hl7-segment-message-type-vs-segments for instructions on how to find the answer by yourself

Comment: possible duplicate of [HL7 - End Visit Notification Message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573548/hl7-end-visit-notification-message)

Comment: Refer Answer on this..

[Refer This...][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23573548/hl7-end-visit-notification-message

Answer (score 1):

As the HL7 messages are open according the specification, you can in theory add as many segments or segment groups after you fulfilled at least the minimal required segments for an ADT^A03 messages as the standard requests.

```
MSH     Message Header
EVN     Event Type
PID     Patient Identification
PV1     Patient Visit
```

HL7 says, that you should ignore fields or segments after the defined, if you do not know them . So there is no limit.
But many communication systems or receivers are limited either by physical (receive stack) or other reasons (strict defined message templates). So in practice you have to come to an agreement with your communication partners.

Comment: This is not correct. Except for locally-defined Z segments, message structures are not open and you can't include any other segment types beyond what are allowed in the message structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can download whichever version of the HL7 [V2.x messaging standard](https://www.hl7.org/implement/standards/product_brief.cfm?product_id=185) you are using and check the exact definition of the A03 trigger event in chapter 3, section 3.3.3. It will show you exactly which segment types are allowed in the ADT_A03 message structure.