# HL7 - End Visit Notification Message

Tags: hl7

I just wanted to know when we send a `End Visit Notification` as Hl7 Message, can we include the below segments in the HL7 Message (`ADT^A03`) when we send End Visit Notification?

```
AIL - Appointment Information - Location Resource
AL1- Patient Allergy Information
CON - Consent Segment
CTD - Contact Data
DG1 - Diagnosis
DMI - DRG Master File Information
FAC - Facility
IAM - Patient Adverse Reaction Information
LAN -Language Detail
NTE -- Notes and Comments
ODS -- Dietary Orders, Supplements, and Preferences
PD1 -- Patient Additional Demographic
PID - Patient Identification
PR1 -- Procedures
PRA -- Practitioner Detail
PRB -- Problem Details
PRD Provider Data
PV1 Patient Visit
PV2 Patient Visit - Additional Information
RF1 Referral Information
TCD Test Code Detail
```

And also I just wanted to know, is there a limit on using the no of segments in a single HL7 Message?

Any help with this really appreciated it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HL7 ADT^A03 - End Visit Notification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23572521/hl7-adta03-end-visit-notification)

Answer (score 0):

ADT/ACK - Discharge/End Visit (Event A03)

An A03 event signals the end of a patient’s stay in a healthcare facility. It signals that the patient’s status
has changed to “discharged” and that a discharge date has been recorded. The patient is no longer in the facility.
The patient’s location prior to discharge should be entered in PV1-3 - Assigned Patient Location.
Chapter 3: Patient Administration

An A03 event can be sent to notify: the pharmacy that the patient’s stay has ended and that entitlement to
drugs has changed accordingly; the nursing system that the patient has been discharged and that the care
plan can be completed; the extended care or home health system that the patient has been discharged and
that the new extended care or home health admission assessment can be scheduled; the finance system that
the patient billing period has ended; and/or the clinical repository that discharge has taken place for the
EMR.

This are the possible segments to be sent in ADT^A03.

[image]

For More Help Refer HL7 Standard Guide V_2.5.1